# How to implement volleyresponse listener using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I am trying to move my volley requests into a class, so I can use it for multiple network calls. I need a way to access the response listener in whatever activity I use in this class. i saw some examples in java, But I am finding it difficult to do achieve this.

```
import android.content.Context
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

interface VolleyResponse{
}

class NetworkCall(LINK:String, 
                  CONTEXT:Context, 
                  CACHE:Boolean, 
                  PARAMS: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap(),
                  SuccessListener: Response.Listener<String>,
                  ErrorListener: Response.ErrorListener ) {

    private  var link:String = LINK
    private var context: Context = CONTEXT
    var cache: Boolean = CACHE
    var PARAMS: HashMap<String,String> = HashMap()

    fun RunTask( ){
        //BUILD the request and listen for error or success
        var request = object : StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,link,
                Response.Listener { response -> { }
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error -> { }
                }) {
            override fun getParams(): HashMap<String, String> {
                return PARAMS
            }
        }
        var RequestQueue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        request.setShouldCache(cache)
        request.setRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, 0F))
    }
}
```

and i call it like this...

```
 fun processLogin() {
        var params:HashMap<String,String> = HashMap()
        params.put("user_email","username")
        params.put("user_password","password")
        var networkCall = NetworkCall("",applicationContext,false,params)
}
```

I just need to be able to access the response listeners in my processLogin function.

Comment: Thank you so much, but maybe you don't understand me...the first line is my NetworkCall class, the processLogin is a function in my login activity...I'll try this and mark it as answered or /if it works..

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define implementations of `Response.Listener<String>` and `Response.ErrorListener` in the `class` where `processLogin` is defined, this can be done as following

```
private val successListener = Response.Listener<String> {
    // Do something when response is received
}

private val errorListener = Response.ErrorListener {
    // Do something when error is received
}
```

now pass these as parameters when you call `processLogin` as following

```
 var networkCall = NetworkCall("",applicationContext,false,params, successListener, errorListener)
```

Finally you need to update your `NetworkCall` class so that these listeners are called on network action

```
fun RunTask( ){
    //BUILD the request and listen for error or success
    var request = object : StringRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,link,
        SuccessListener,  // Pass listeners to request
        ErrorListener) {
        override fun getParams(): HashMap<String, String> {
            return PARAMS
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is focused on my NetworkCall class...How do i call the Listener on another activity? I don't want to have to declare a listener every time i need to make a network call.. I just want to access the Listener after i initialize my NetworkCall class and execute the "RunTask" function. I hope you get a clearer picture now?